# How to undo DISPLAY export in linux?

Tags: linux, export

I have exported my X display to another computer using this command:

> export DISPLAY=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:0.0

How can I undo it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can say:

```
unset DISPLAY
```

to unset it.

If you want to set the display to the local system, say:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Comment: I still cannot see anything after executing applications that use X. `GtkWarning: could not open display`